# Jenkins started selenium, but can't access chrome localStorage

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, jenkins, intern

I use Jenkins to start a selenium standalone serve with chrome driver. It starts OK. But when I use it with intern tests, the chrome tests don't start. I got this in the log:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: 
DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': 
Access is denied for this document.
```

If I start selenium locally, everything works fine. Note Jenkins slave service uses the same user as the local login.

Ther batch script I used to start Jenkins is this:

```
start cmd /c java -jar C:\Jenkins\workspace\app\util\selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Jenkins\workspace\app\util\chromedriver.exe 2^> seleniumLog.txt
```

Why does it not work when I start selenium from Jenkins?

Comment: What environmental differences are there? Same machine (Windows slaves?)...Chrome version? ChromeDriver version? Windows version?

Comment: @Arran, all the same. Same batch file ran on the same machine. Only difference is running from Jenkins and running manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jenkins as a service standalone server can't create real window.

You can use workaround. Create Node and run from usual user (auto startup). Run your Job on that node

P.S.

For normal screenshot (not black screen) you can put session to Console "tscon RDP-tcp#0 /dest:console" (set screen resolution by QRes tool).

Comment: I talked to my manager before and he didn't want to run it from auto startup. He wants to start selenium from Jenkins. I know Jenkins service can't create real window. But it doesn't matter to me.